# Javascipt Trying to get contents of <a> tage

Tags: javascript, html, tags, extract

I have been trying to get full detail of a series of  tags on an HTML page
I can get the ID and text but all other values elude me
The HTML looks like this

```html
<a class="cuenta" codigo="1.1.1.1" nombre="Caja" data-placement="right" data-popover-content="#popover_content_wrapper" data-title="Menú Opciones" data-trigger="focus" desc="1.1.1.1 Caja" href="javascript:void(0);" id="619060" padre="619059" rel="" style="color:black;">1.1.1.1 Caja</a>
```

1.1.1.1 Caja

The code that works

```html
var x = document.querySelectorAll("a");
var myarray = []
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
var allcontent = x[i].elements
var nametext = x[i].textContent;
var cleantext = nametext.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
var classtype = x[i].class;
var nombretxt = x[i].nombre;
var idno = x[i].id;
var padreno = x[i].padre;
myarray.push([idno,nametext]);
};
function make_table() {
    var table = '<table><thead><th>idno</th><th>nametext</th></thead><tbody>';
   for (var i=0; i<myarray.length; i++) {
            table += '<tr><td>'+ myarray[i][0] + '</td><td>'+myarray[i][1]+'</td></tr>';
    };
 
    var w = window.open("");
w.document.write(table); 
}
make_table()
```

I need to get the values of class= codigo= padre= nombre= into the array as well
but experimenting with var nombretxt = x[i].nombre; and similar does not return a value

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Using DOM's [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) property

```js
const aTag = document.querySelector("a");
let padreno = aTag.getAttribute("padre");
let classtype = aTag.getAttribute("class");
let nombre = aTag.getAttribute("nombre");
console.log({ padreno, classtype, nombre });
//{padreno: '619059', classtype: 'cuenta', nombre: 'Caja'}
```

```html
<a
    class="cuenta"
    codigo="1.1.1.1"
    nombre="Caja"
    data-placement="right"
    data-popover-content="#popover_content_wrapper"
    data-title="Menú Opciones"
    data-trigger="focus"
    desc="1.1.1.1 Caja"
    href="javascript:void(0);"
    id="619060"
    padre="619059"
    rel=""
    style="color: black"
    >1.1.1.1 Caja</a
>
```